# Destroying certain blocks within the range of an entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to find out how to destroy certain blocks in the range of an entity.
[image: Example]

Command block detects that cracked stone bricks is in range of the TNT item entity and then destroys the cracked stone bricks.

Comment: Are you trying to get the TNT to destroy only the cracked stone bricks? I think the question is unclear.

Comment: @sensiwoo yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. All you need are two commands in repeat command blocks, and to add a new scoreboard objective.

First, run this command once:

> /scoreboard objectives add TNT dummy

Then in the first command block (set to repeat mode):

> /scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] TNT 1 {Item:{id:minecraft:tnt}}

Finally, in a second command block (also set to repeat):

> /execute @e[score_TNT_min=1] ~ ~ ~ fill ~2 ~2 ~2 ~-2 ~-2 ~-2 minecraft:air 0  replace minecraft:stonebrick 2

This will replace any stone bricks in a 5x5x5 cube around the item with air. I haven't tested this, so it might not work, but I think it will. Good luck!